# According to Dispensationalism is "the land" of Ezekiel 37:24-28 interpreted as "Heaven"?

Tags: eschatology, dispensationalism, ezekiel

> ESV Ezekiel 37:
>
> 24“My servant David shall be king over them, and they shall all have one shepherd. **They shall walk in my rules and be careful to obey my statutes**. 25**They shall dwell in the land that I gave to my servant Jacob, where your fathers lived. They and their children and their children’s children shall dwell there forever**, and David my servant shall be their prince forever. 26I will make a covenant of peace with them. It shall be an everlasting covenant with them. And **I will set them in their land** and multiply them, and will set my sanctuary in their midst forevermore. 27My dwelling place shall be with them, and I will be their God, and they shall be my people. 28Then the nations will know that I am the LORD who sanctifies Israel, when my sanctuary is in their midst forevermore.”

And are the "rules and statutes" the Torah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that Dispensationalism sees this section of Ezekiel as the millennial reign. I suppose the rules are Torah.

> They and their children and their children’s children will live there forever, and David my servant will be their prince forever” (37:24–25). Though some have attempted to take this prophecy in less than its literal meaning, the clear statement is that David, who is now dead and whose body is in his tomb in Jerusalem (Acts 2:29), will be resurrected. This will occur at the second coming (Dan. 12:1–3), indicating plainly that the restoration of Israel will be subsequent to, not before, the second coming. This requires Christ’s coming before the millennium or in fulfillment of the premillennial promises. The promise that David would be her prince forever must be interpreted as being fulfilled in the thousand-year reign.

Walvoord, John F.. Every Prophecy of the Bible: Clear Explanations for Uncertain Times (p. 183). David C. Cook. Kindle Edition.

Here is Darby,

> Chapter 37 reveals the definitive blessing of the people as a fact, without entering into any details of the events that terminate in this blessing. The dry bones of Israel, of the nation as a whole, are gathered together by the power of God. God accomplishes this work by His Spirit, but by His Spirit acting in power on His people to produce certain effects rather than in giving spiritual life (although it is not to be doubted that those who are blessed among the Jews will be spiritually quickened). The result of this intervention of God is that the dispersed of Israel, hitherto divided into two peoples, are gathered together in the earth, reunited under one Head, as one nation. It is the resurrection of the nation, which was really dead and buried. But God opens their graves and places them again in their land restored to life as a nation. The fact of their division before this operation of God is recognized. But the result of the operation is Israel in their unity as a people. One king should reign over them. This, under God's hand, is the result of all their iniquity, and of the devices of the enemies who had carried them into captivity. David (that is, Christ) should be their king. They should be thoroughly cleansed by God Himself. They should walk in His statutes and His judgments, and dwell forever in their land. The sanctuary of God should be in their midst for evermore; His tabernacle, His dwelling-place, should be among them, He their God and they His people. The heathen should know that Jehovah sanctified Israel when His sanctuary should be there forever. It is the full national blessing of Israel from the Lord Jehovah.

[Darby's Bible Synopsis](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/darby/ezekiel/37.htm)

Comment: thank you so much for this excellent informative answer. I was under the impression that Dispensationalists saw everything as being fulfilled in "Heaven".

Comment: You're welcome. Premillennialism, which Dispensationalism is part of, likes literal interpretation and earthly fulfillment.